# different between card reader to usb using c#

Tags: c#, usb, cardreader

I build a scanner that takes all drive's with DriveInfo .
how i Discerning between drive from card reader and drive from usb ??
thanks....

---

is the same member - Removable!!
i try this , but must to be a diffrent from card reader to usb device!!
sombody ??

Comment: are you meaning 'card reader' that's integrated onto the motherboard or other dedicated hardware interface for CompactFlash or Secure Digital cards? Are you also trying to differentiate between USB removable thumbdrives, or USB hard drives?

Comment: i meaninig  dedicated hardware interface for CompactFlash .
and yes,i try and not found what's the different !!

Answer (score 2):

I would see if the [DriveInfo.DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) returns a different drive type for the card reader and the usb drive. [Here's a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx) of what drive types DriveInfo contains.

Comment: is the same member - Removable!!
i try this , but must to be a diffrent from card reader to usb device!!
sombody ??

Comment: USB and Memory cards will all be listed as 'Removable'

Comment: @noam: You can prevent this kind of answers by asking better questions. You should have mentioned what you already tried.