# How can i get all USB drives (plugged in)

Tags: c#, wpf, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get List Of USB Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-usb-devices)

Im making a WPF app.

Im looking for a way to list all plugged in USB devices (disks!) in my comboBox.

I can list all drives using DriveInfo.GetDrives(), but is there a simple way to filter that to USB devices?

thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get List Of USB Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-usb-devices)
and [different between card reader to usb using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329745/different-between-card-reader-to-usb-using-c/3329822#3329822)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
 {
     if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
     {
      ..
     }
 }
```

Comment: Be careful with this that you don't (occasionally, never with a debugger attached) get a horrible messagebox from somewhere deep in Windows asking you to insert a disk into a drive.

Comment: i have additional question.
My combobox had binding to property (type List) on my viewmodel.
It works fine, but if i plug in USB disk i have to reload the window in order to repopulate combobox. Is there a way that i could repopulate combobox once the USB devide is plugged in/ out ?

Comment: also i shrinked the code u gave me to:
return DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).ToList();

Comment: Use ObservableCollection in viewmodel to bind to the Combobox. Create a DispatcherTimer with some interval to check for Drives, if any new drives found add that to the observablecollection; this is will displayed in the UI.

Comment: This does not work with some external hard drives. At the moment the only way to detect if it is a hard disk connected via USB is to use some ugly WMI stuff. You can see a code sample at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331043/get-list-of-connected-usb-devices

Comment: Isn't this return all the removable drives? including SATA which is not a USB?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9f9eb8f5-297f-4acd-a9af-aafbe384fd71/

The accepted answer at that link seems to do what you're asking.

Comment: thanx, ive been looking into that solution before, but it seemed too complicated ...